# Create EMR Hive cluster with glue catalog using CLI

Tags: hive, aws-cli, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I would like to create EMR Hive cluster, which will use Glue as data catalog, using AWS CLI.
I didn't find anything related to that in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html) or searching in other places.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we create a [configuration classification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html) named emr.json that specifies AWS Glue Data Catalog as the metastore for Hive:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "hive-site",
    "Properties": {
      "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory",
      "hive.metastore.schema.verification": "false"
    }
  }
]
```

Note: On EMR release version 5.28.0, 5.28.1, or 5.29.0, if you're creating a cluster using the AWS Glue Data Catalog as the metastore, we set the hive.metastore.schema.verification to false.

Finally, we combine the configuration classification file with our final command as follows :

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "syumaK-cluster" --configurations file://emr.json --release-label emr-5.28.0 --use-default-roles --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Spark Name=Hive Name=HUE --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m1.medium InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m1.medium
```

Response:

```
{
    "ClusterId": "j-2NZ6xxxxxx", 
    "ClusterArn": "arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:1925xxxxx:cluster/j-2NZ6xxxxxx"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! If someone is interested to do the same with Presto, here is the required conf: [
  {
   "Classification": "presto-connector-hive",
   "Properties": {
     "hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled": "true"
    }
  }
]